# What is <? super T> syntax?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble understanding the following syntax:

```
public class SortedList< T extends Comparable< ? super T> > extends LinkedList< T >
```

I see that class SortedList extends LinkedList. I just don't know what

```
T extends Comparable< ? super T>
```

means.

My understanding of it so far is that type T must be a type that implements Comparable...but what is `< ? super T >`?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

super in Generics is the opposite of extends. Instead of saying the comparable's generic type has to be a subclass of T, it is saying it has to be a superclass of T. The distinction is important because extends tells you what you can get out of a class (you get at least this, perhaps a subclass). super tells you what you can put into the class (at most this, perhaps a superclass).

In this specific case, what it is saying is that the type has to implement comparable of itself or its superclass. So consider java.util.Date. It implements `Comparable<Date>`. But what about java.sql.Date? It implements `Comparable<java.util.Date>` as well.

Without the super signature, SortedList would not be able accept the type of java.sql.Date, because it doesn't implement a Comparable of itself, but rather of a super class of itself.

Comment: I see. So then given that class, would Collection< Object > list = new SortedList< Object>(); be a valid statement?

Comment: @aloh, no it would not because Object does not implement Comparable.

Comment: I am sorry, I know the question is a bit old, but what can we say if we instead write `Comparable<? extends T>`. What would it mean and why the code does not compile?

Comment: @tonix in that case we are saying that type ? must be a subclass of this generic type T, e.g. if we say T is Number, the ? must be Integer,Double, Short etc

Answer (score 103):

It's a lower-bounded wildcard.

#### [JLS 4.5.1 Type Arguments and Wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.5.1)

> Wildcards are useful in situations where only partial knowledge about the type parameter is required. [...] An upper bound is signified by the syntax:
>
> ```
> ? extends B
> ```
>
> where `B` is the upper bound. [...] it is permissible to declare lower bounds on a wildcard, using the syntax:
>
> ```
> ? super B
> ```
>
> where `B` is a lower bound.

A `List<? super Integer>`, for example, includes `List<Integer>`, `List<Number>`, and `List<Object>`.

Wildcards are used to make generics more powerful and flexible; bounds are used to maintain type safety.

#### See also

- [Java language guide/Generics/More Fun with wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)

---

As to how this is useful in `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, it's when you have something like `Cat extends Animal implements Comparable<Animal>`.

Look at the signature of [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

Therefore, with a `List<Cat> listOfCat`, you can now `Collections.sort(listOfCat)`.

Had it been declared as follows:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

then you'd have to have `Cat implements Comparable<Cat>` to use `sort`. By using the `? super T` bounded wildcard, `Collections.sort` becomes more flexible.

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility*

  - Also, PECS principle: "producer `extends` consumer `super`"

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that though - the question isn't about `? super T`, it is about `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Comment: Ah, I see. Those all implement Comparable. What about the super keyword?

Comment: Not really! If you look at docs, you'll realize it's not simply a bounded wildcard.

Comment: Just for clarification, my previous comment was aimed at your initial response which was just 3-4 lines.

Comment: This is a world clearer than the accpted answer...

Comment: why you use a more complicated example ?

Answer (score 16):

It means that `T` must implement `Comparable<T itself or one of T's superclasses>`
The sense is that because `SortedList` is sorted, it must know how to compare two classes of its generics `T` parameter. That's why `T` must implement `Comparable<T itself or one of T's superclasses>`

Answer (score 7):

It means that the type `T` must implement `Comparable` of `T` or one of its super classes.

For example, if `A` extends `B`, if you want to use `SortedList<A>`, `A` must implement `Comparable<A>` or `Comparable<B>`, or in fact just `Comparable`.

This allows the list of `A`s to be constructed with any valid comparator.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example:

1. Using a type parameter defined in the class declaration

   public class ArrayList extends AbstractList ... {
        public boolean add(E o)             // You can use the "E" here ONLY because it's already been defined as part of the class
2. Using a type parameter that was NOT defined in the class declaration

   ```
   public <T extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<T> list)
                                               // Here we can use <T> because we declared "T" earlier in the method declaration
   ```

   If the class itself doesn't use a type parameter, you can still specify one for a method, by declaring it in a really unusual (but available) space  - before the return type. This method says that T can be "any type of Animal".

NOTE:

```
public <T extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<T> list)             

is NOT same as              

public void takeThing(ArrayList<Animal> list)
```

Both are legal, but they are different. The first one indicates that you can pass in a ArrayList object instantiated as Animal or any Animal subtype like ArrayList, ArrayList or ArrayList. But, you can only pass ArrayList in the second, and NOT any of the subtypes.