# Java Collections static method min

Tags: java

Can someone please explain this rather cryptic method signature from the `Collections` class?

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> 
        T min(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Type "T" is an Object and implements the "Comparable" interface; the min method returns an object of type T and takes a Collection of T as input.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the method signature after `static` and before return type is called type constraints. In your case, the type constraints specifies that the type `T` should be subclass of `Object` and should implement interface `Comparable`.

<strike>(The `Object` part is redundant; and hence the constraint can be written more briefly as `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`).</strike>

`<? super T>` and `<? extends T>` are called variance annotations. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827585/java-syntax-question-what-is-super-t).

---

**EDIT**: As @Petros said in the comment below, the inclusion of `extends Object` might seem redundant, but it changes the erasure of T to be `Object` rather than `Comparable`.

The following chart [[Source](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ108)] may help understand this better:

```
Type Parameters                              Type Erasure
-------------------------------------------------------------
<T>                                          Object
<T extends Number>                           Number
<T extends Comparable<T>>                    Comparable
<T extends Cloneable & Comparable<T>>        Cloneable
<T extends Object & Comparable<T>>           Object
<S, T extends S>                             Object, Object
```

Comment: So, the <T extends Object> is redundant and it could just be <T>?

Comment: @Petros: Every class in Java is subclass of `Object`. Hence the `Object` _part_ is redundant. The other constraint - `extends Comparable` - needs to be retained.

Comment: @missingfactor: Actually I just found out that <T extends Object> is not redundant. It says to the compiler that the erasure of T should be Object instead of Comparable.

Comment: Hi, in The Java Programming Language says "The inclusion of "extends Object " might seem redundant, but it changes the erasure of T to be Object rather than Comparable."

Comment: @Petros: Yes, you are correct. I didn't know about this feature. Thanks so much for pointing out. Learn something new every day! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adam's description.
Parameter T is needed for argument collection: Collection

So, as minimum we need the following method prototype:

```
public static <T> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

But we have to be able to compare the collection element. So, each element must implement Comparable and our prototype becomes more complicated:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

But comparable interface itself is parametrized. To avoid compilation warning we have to say:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

Due to each class in Java automatically extends Object I really do not understand why did they make this prototype more complicated, i.e. wrote explicitly that T extends Object. Typically generics definitions like

```
T extends A & B
```

are used when A and B are interfaces.

I am not sure that my answer helps because probably it asks yet another question. I'd be happy of somebody can explain why return type

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> T
```

was not complicated enough and they said

```
<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll limit the answer to the "cryptic" parts and assume you understand `public`, `static` and basic generics like `Collections<T>`.

### 1. Collection<? extends T>

The `?` is a wildcard, means any (or unknown) type.

The `extends` keyword means that the type parameter for the `Collection` must extend the given type `T`.  In general this is used when an object is used as a "**producer**" of elements of type `T`.  In this case this is true because for doing comparison elements of type `T` are only read from the collection.

The reason for this?  This allows for more flexibility than if just `Collection<T>` was used. *Example*: the following works:

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
Number n = Collections.min(integers);
```

In the above example, `T` equals `Number` but the collection's type is `Integer`, which extends `Number`.

### 2. Comparable<? super T>

`?` is again a wildcard.

The `super` keyword means that the type parameter for the `Comparable` must be a super type of the given type `T`.  In general this is used when an object is only used as a "**consumer**" of elements of type `T`.  In this case this is true because the `compareTo` method from `Comparable<T>` only takes ("consumes") an argument of type `T` but doesn't return it.

The reason for this?  This allows for greater flexibility: although any class `X` that implements `Comparable` will usually implement `Comparable<X>`, in theory it could implement `Comparable<Y>`, even without `Y` being a super type of `X` (although that would be weird and not according to the intended use of `Comparable`).  As long as `Y` is a super type of `X`, `X` is allowed as return type in a call to this method.

The above two points are usually referred to as the *PECS* principle (Producer Extends, Consumer Super).

### 3. &

This is used to combine multiple types.  In this case `Object` was added as a first type to make sure the type after erasure is `Object` instead of `Comparable`, probably for compatibility reasons with libraries compiled with previous java versions that did not have generics (just a guess).