# Problem with <T extends Comparable<? super T>>

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a three class: 1.class `Algorithm` having `max()` finding maximum value in a `Collection`:

```
public class Algorithm {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
        T max = coll.iterator().next();

        for (T elm : coll) {
            if (max.compareTo(elm) < 0)
                max = elm;
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

2.Class `Fruit`:

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
    private String name;
    private int size;

    public Fruit(String name, int size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int compareTo(Fruit that) {
        if (size < that.size)
            return -1;
        else if (size == that.size)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

3.class `Apple` extending `Fruit`:

```
public class Apple extends Fruit {
    public Apple(int size) {
        super("Apple", size);
    }
}
```

Now the question is this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Apple a1 = new Apple(10);
        Apple a2 = new Apple(34);

        List<Apple> apples = Arrays.<Apple>asList(a1, a2);

        System.out.println(Collections.max(apples).size);
    }
}
```

According to this post [Java - Syntax Question: What is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827585/java-syntax-question-what-is-super-t)  I should wrote it this way: `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)`. But it is working fine now.Why? Class `Apple` does not implement `Comparable<Apple>` and there is no `super`.

[UPDATE]
Java Generics and Collections Book says:

> Without the `super` wildcard, finding the maximum of a `List<Apple>`
>   would be illegal, even though finding the maximum of a `List<Fruit>` is
>   permitted.

Comment: FYI: Guava's [`Ints`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html) class has a [`compare(int, int)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) method to make `int` comparisons easier.

Comment: @AdamPaynter Java 7's `Integer` class now provides that same method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we changed the `max` method to this:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

You would not be able to get the `max` of a `List<Apple>` because `Apple` does not implement `Comparable<Apple>`, it implements `Comparable<Fruit>`. But you and I know perfectly well that an `Apple` knows how to compare itself to another `Fruit` because it inherited that functionality.

We fix the problem by changing the declaration of `max` to this:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

This means that we accept any class `T` such that:

1. `T implements Comparable<T>`, **or...**
2. `T implements Comparable<X>` for some `X` such that `X` is a super class of `T`

In order to find the `max`, we must be sure that any instance of `T` can safely accept another instance of `T` as an argument to its `compare` method.

In the first scenario, it is obvious that any instance of `T` can safely accept another instance of `T` as an argument to its `compare(T)` method.

In the second scenario, any instance of `T` can safely accept another instance of `T` as an argument to its `compare(X)` method because all instances of `T` are also instances of `X`.

Your example illustrates the second scenario, where `T` corresponds to `Apple` and `X` corresponds to `Fruit`.

Answer (score 1):

You use `Collections.max(apples)` instead of `Algorithm.max`.

`Collections.max` has slightly different declaration:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

Comment: My question is: without `Comparable<? super T>` it should not work because with this `Comparable<T>` class `Apple` should implement `Comparable<Apple>` which isn't implemented here.

Comment: When I change `Collections.max` to `Algorithm.max` in your sample it doesn't work as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for bringing this back but I think it's important. Has your code stopped working properly when changed from Collections.max() to Algorithm.max()? I've done a simmilar test in jdk8 and I don't understand why it's working fine while according to Java Generics and Collections it should not.

I have a Fruit abstract class (implementing Comparable):

```
public abstract class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
    private String name;
    private int size;

    public Fruit(String name, int size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int compareTo(Fruit that) {
        if (size < that.size)
            return -1;
        else if (size == that.size)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Then I have a Apple extending Fruit class:

```
public class Apple extends Fruit {
    public Apple(String name, int size) {
        super(name, size);
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
 public class GenericsTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        final Apple a1 = new Apple("apple1", 50);
        final Apple a2 = new Apple("apple2", 70);
        final Apple a3 = new Apple("apple3", 34);

        final List<Apple> apples = Lists.newArrayList(a1, a2, a3);

        System.out.println(GenericsTest.max(apples).getSize());
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
        T max = coll.iterator().next();

        for (T elm : coll) {
            if (max.compareTo(elm) < 0)
                max = elm;
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

The code is working while there is no ? super T in the max method's signature and the List is of Apple type. According to the quote you mentioned it shouldn't be working. I seem to be puzzled here...

Answer (score 0):

let's try to see what happens when you remove <? super T>

```
public class CollectionMinSignature {
    
    public static <T extends Object & Comparable</*? super*/ T>> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    
        Iterator<? extends T> i = coll.iterator();
        T candidate = i.next();

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            T next = i.next();
            if (next.compareTo(candidate) < 0)
                candidate = next;
        }
        return candidate;
    }
    
    public static class A implements Comparable<A> {
        private int i;
        public A (int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(A a) {
            return this.getVal() - a.getVal();
        }
        public String toString() {
            return Integer.toString(i);
        }
        public int getVal() {
            return this.i;
        }
    }
    public static class B extends A {
        public B(int i) {
            super(i);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Collection<B> coll = new ArrayList<B>(List.of(new B(0), new B(1), new B(-1)));
    
    B b = min(coll); /*it doesn't work*/
    B b2 = Collections.min(coll); /*it works*/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).