# Comparable<? super T> vs. Comparable<T>

Tags: java, wildcard

I can't see any difference between this default sort method(from java.util.Collections)

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
      //implementation
}
```

..and this :

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mySort(List<T> list) {
    //implementation
}
```

Although I know about the differences between the 'upper' and 'lower' bounded wildcards,I still don't understand why they use '? super T' instead of simple 'T' in this case.If I use these methods,I get the same result with both of them.Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with <T extends Comparable<? super T>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704085/problem-with-t-extends-comparable-super-t)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your version, the following will not compile:

```
class Base implements Comparable<Base> { ... }

class Derived extends Base { ... }

List<Derived> list = ...;

mySort(list);
```

`Derived` does **not** extend `Comparable<Derived>`.  However, it does extend `Comparable<Base>` (and thus, `Comparable<? super Derived>`).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, "<? super T>" is a way to recognize that the CompareTo method is not implemented in T itself, but inherited by a SuperClass.