# Java wildcards with super

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, super, comparable

I read that using a wildcard with super like this:

```
public class MyClass <T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
   ...
}
```

instead of:

```
public class MyClass <T extends Comparable<T>> {
   ...
}
```

could make the class 'more generic', but I do not understand why.

Can someone provide some concrete examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics: What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is <? super T> syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827585/what-is-super-t-syntax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This way you can supply a class for T, which does not for itself implements Comparable, but inherits from a class implementing Comparable.

E.g.

```
class Baseclass implements Comparable<Baseclass> {
...
}

class Inherited extends Baseclass {
...
}
```

With a specification like

```
public class MyClass <T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
...
}
```

you can use `MyClass<Inherited>`, and `MyClass<Baseclass>`, but with

```
public class MyClass <T extends Comparable<T>> {
...
}
```

you can only use `MyClass<Baseclass>`

Comment: I actually tried that. I created a class Fruit which implements Comparable<Fruit> and 2 subclasses: Apple and Orange. Then, I tried to use a method written in this form <T extends Comparable<T>> (note that I used no super keyword) and it compared apples with oranges nevertheless. Do you have any idea why? It should not work according to your answer.

Comment: Here is my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629547/java-wildcard-with-super-unexpected-behaviour?noredirect=1#comment38171540_24629547

Comment: @Kami You will see that when your MyClass has getters and setters accepting or delivering Objects of type T. This will not work without super.