# What mean this expression in Generic

Tags: java, generics, comparable

Can someone please explain to me what this expression in java means:

```
class BinaryNode<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
```

What does "AnyType extends Comparable" mean?

Comment: There's this thing called the Internet, see? And you can use it to [search for information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827585/what-is-super-t-syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declares a generic type parameter called `AnyType`.  The rest of the declaration, `extends Comparable<? super AnyType>`, places an upper bound on what `AnyType` can be.  Specifically, whatever `AnyType` is must be `Comparable`, and `Comparable`'s type argument can be what `AnyType` is, or anything that is a superclass of that type.  E.g. it could be `Integer`, because `Integer` is `Comparable<Integer>`.  However, it could be some class that is `Comparable<Object>`, because `Object` is the superclass to all object types.