# Java generics wildcards use

Tags: java

I am learning Java and am puzzled as to the difference between the two following definitions:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>
    T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {
   ...
}
```

(taken from the answer to exercise 8 in the oracle java tutorial: [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/QandE/generics-answers.html))
and

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    T max (List<T> list, int begin, int end) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `Object &` is basically meaningless.

Comment: Depends. Without context yes, but `Collections.max(Collection<? extends T> coll)` in the official API uses `Object &`  as part of its signature to preserve binary compatibility. So it's not always meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Here, have a look at this thread:

[What is <? super T> syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827585/what-is-super-t-syntax)

You should see the difference between the two then. Basically the former is more flexible in what you can use as T.

Comment: This should be a flag for duplicate, not an answer.

Comment: Ahh!!! I seem to have forgotten that even if  A extends B, Comparable<A> does not extend/implement Comparable<B>. In the example above it also seems to meen that the wildcard does not need to "expand" to the same type in the Comparable and the List.