# How to sort an array list of different object types using Comparable interface

Tags: java

This is part of an assignment for class, and I can't figure out what this statement means to save my own life.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(Arraylist<T> list){}
```

The method doesn't have an implementation because I'm supposed to do that myself. The list to be sorted will contain an `Integer` type, a `Double` type, and a `String` type.

How the hell am I supposed to sort a list of different object types using `Comparable` and what the hell does `Comparable<? super T>` mean?

My class text book is super vague and abstruse and this statement is so specific, I have no idea where to find it on the internet.

**edit:**

Okay, I finally understood the instructions =( I do not have to sort a list of different item types. I'm supposed to sort three different list of the same item type. But I still don't understand

`Comparable<? super T>`

Comment: Why the hell are you storing different object types in one list?!

Comment: What is the logic for sorting?

Comment: How would you sort `Integer`s, `Double`s and `String`s? Is "Bob the Builder" greater than 17.43 or less than it?

Comment: @Prexx I don't know! Because it's in the instructions as far as I can tell.

Comment: He's not receiving different object in an arraylist, he's receiving an arraylist of type T. T could be any type of object, not a mix of different Objects.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker You are correct. What does `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you create an implementation for a generic sorting method.

If you call the 'sort' method with an arraylist full of string, the method will sort these strings:

```
public static <String> void sort(Arraylist<String> list){}
```

If you call the same method with an arraylist full of long values, it will sort long values:

```
public static <Long> void sort(Arraylist<Long> list){}
```

You are not going to sort strings with longs.

Example of another generic method could be:

```
public static <T> void print(T object){
    System.out.println(object.toString());
}

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(Arraylist<T> list){}
```

Update:

You want a generictype that extends T

```
<T extends Comparable<>
```

Comparable also needs a generic type that is a superclass of your first generic type.

```
<? super T>
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally understood the question. I'm having trouble understanding the statement `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: You want a generictype that extends T (<T extends Comparable<>) and Comparable also needs a generic type that is a superclass of your first generic type. See my update

Comment: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` can be read as: `T` extends a `Comparable` of a type that is a super type of `T`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2827616/715593).

Answer (score 4):

The list you get contains only one type `T`, and you know about `T`that it is a subtype of `Comparable<? super T>`.

So, if you would have a subtype of `Comparable<T>` instead, things would be pretty simple: You know that your type has a `compareTo(T t)` method you could use for sorting.

But imagine you get the type `java.sql.Timestamp` as your `T`. It doesn't implement `Comparable<Timestamp>` but `Comparable<Date>`. So it has a method `compareTo(Date)`. However, this is *not a problem*, because a `Timestamp` *is* a `Date`, so you could still use the method to compare two `Timestamp`s. But having `Comparable<T>` in the signature wouldn't allow to pass a `ArrayList<Timestamp>`, it is too restrictive.

This is exactly why the given signature allows not only subclasses of `Comparable<T>`, but of `Comparable<? super T>` as list elements. This covers cases like the `Timestamp` example, because a comparison function for *supertypes* is sufficient for your purpose.

If you want to learn more about this idea, search for "contra variance".

Comment: Okay, thanks. So `Timestamp` extends `Date` but `Timestamp` doesn't have it's own `compareTo` method. Therefore, I have to specify that I can fall back on the the `compareTo` method in `Date`. Is that more or less the idea?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. `Timestamp` has actually its own implementation of `compareTo(Date)`, but this is an implementation detail. BTW, this part of the Java API is widely considered a design flaw (e.g. `data.compareTo(timestamp)` can give a result of 0 when `timestamp.compareTo(date)` does not, for the same values for `date` and `timestamp`).