# How do I create a function that can take in an array of any object and sort it?

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

My computer science teacher gave me a challenge to create a function that can take in an array of any object and sort it using bubble sort. Since the Object class is the parent class of all classes, I thought of taking in an array of Objects but I can't really sort it since the Object class doesn't have a comparable. I'm kind of stuck right now because I don't know what to pass in to the function. My teacher said that I should pass in a Comparable interface but I'm afraid I don't know enough to know what he means by that.

This is what I tried but I know it doesn't work:

```
public static void bubble(Object arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[j + 1]) > 0) {
                Object temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know much about Java so any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubble(T[] arr)` or `public static <T> void bubble(T[] arr, Comparator<T> comp)` (I think your teacher wants the first one though). Or maybe you weren't expected to find the first one and should do `public static void bubble(Comparable[] arr)`.

Comment: I got that to work, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with your confusion! Indeed, not all objects have a comparator, and are thus incomparable; it sounds like your teacher wants your method to reject objects like this.

You can enforce the `bubble` method to only accept `Comparable` objects as follows:

`public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubble(T[] arr)`

This method header takes advantage of a java concept called [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)-- basically a variable which represents a type, instead of an object. In this case, your generic variable is `T`. Thus, if the method was called with `bubble(new Box[])`, then `T` would represent the type `Box`.

The `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` says: "`T` must implement `Comparable` that can sort `T`" You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827585/what-is-super-t-syntax).